# Django views : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I loop through multiple question stored in my DB each question has 5 answers(openness,conscientiousness,extraversion,agreeableness,neuroticism) and am trying to count how many times each answers is repeated and store the scores

Models :

```
class Reponses(models.Model):
    ScoreOp = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    ScoreCon = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    ScoreExt = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    ScoreAgr = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    ScoreNeu = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    Product = models.OneToOneField("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class Personalite(models.Model):
    Question = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    openness = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    conscientiousness = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    extraversion = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    agreeableness = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    neuroticism = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    models.ForeignKey("Reponses", on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Views :

```
def home_views(request):
questions= Personalite.objects.all()
product = Product.objects.get(id=5)
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        reponse = Reponses.objects.create()
        reponse = Reponses(Product= product)
        allRep = []
        allRep = request.POST.getlist('poll')
        for Rep in allRep:
            print(Rep)
            if Rep == 'openness':
                reponse.ScoreOp = reponse.ScoreOp + 1

            elif Rep == 'conscientiousness':
                reponse.ScoreCon += 1

            elif Rep == 'extraversion':
                reponse.ScoreExt += 1

            elif Rep == 'agreeableness':
                reponse.ScoreAgr += 1

            elif Rep == 'neuroticism':
                reponse.ScoreNeu += 1
            else :
                print('HAHAHAHHAHAAH')
            
        reponse.save()
    except NameError:
        print("An exception occurred",NameError)

context={
    'questions':questions
}
return render(request , "home.html",context)
```

Comment: What is your question and what error occurred at what line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reponse = Reponses(Product= product)` this doesn't saves the response object you need to call the `save()` method so `reponse.ScoreOp`  is None.

Try this.

First create the response object properly.

```
 reponse = Reponses.objects.create(Product=product)
```

And also instead of specifying the `null=True` to the integer field provide the default value `0`.

```
ScoreOp = models.IntegerField(default=0) # properly migrate after change in model
```

Now in the views.

```
 if Rep == 'openness':
      reponse.ScoreOp += 1
```